# math in JavaScript will not run

Tags: javascript

amount x .25 x month + amount / month = result. I have tried but the result is always wrong.

```
Amount: <input id="amount" type="text" />
Month: <input id="month" type="text" />

<input type="submit" onclick="output();">

<p id="result"> </p>

<script>
    function output(){
        var amount = parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value);
        var month = parseInt(document.getElementById('month').value);
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = amount * .25 * month + amount/month;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So... what do you get, and what did you expect? Also, what are the values of `amount` and `month`, and do they match with what you expect them to be?

Comment: `amount * .25 * month + amount/month` Do you know the order of operations here?

Comment: BTW, given that the values are used in multiplication and division before being added, there is no need for *parseInt* unless you wish to truncate floating point values or need to trim trailing non–digits.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your issue is twofold.

1) Order of operations. Use parentheses to specify how things should be computed.

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = amount * .25 * month + (amount/month);
```

2) If your intention with var amount is floating point numbers (Ex: 12.45), use `parseFloat` instead.

```
var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);
```

Relevant reading material

1. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp
2. http://javascript.about.com/od/variablesandoperators/a/vop08.htm

Comment: The parenthesis your mentioned are not relevant here... It does't matter if they are here or not.

Comment: The use of *parseInt* is only required for certain circumstances, *parseFloat* is not required at all.

Comment: Parenthesis -may- be relevant depending how the users formula is defined. Additionally, parseInt('12.45') is 12. If this users data is in dollar and cent amounts, all calculated fields would vary from what would be expected if entered into a calculator. Not to say this had to be parsed at all. The point was merely illuminating the possibly inappropriate function use.

Answer (score 0):

You provide no indication of why you consider the result to be wrong. However, it may be that the use of *parseInt* is truncation floating point values.

The values of form controls are always strings, however when used in mathematic operations other than addition, they are automatically converted to numbers as if by `Number(value)`. Since the first operation performed on each value is either multiplication or division, you can just do that:

```js
function output(){
    var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = (amount * .25 * month + amount/month).toFixed(2);
}
```

```html
Amount: <input id="amount" type="text">
Month: <input id="month" type="text">
<input type="submit" onclick="output();">
<p id="result"></p>
```

However, for robustness, it's a good idea to validate the input value first, then explicitly convert to number. The first can be done with a simple regular expression, the second using unary `+`. There are plenty of good answers here about how to do both.